# "Invalid Column Name" error thrown by Access Reports?

Tags: ms-access, group-by

I am attempting to sum over a detail grouping on a specific field in Microsoft Access, and assign that sum to a field in the general grouping. When I try to run the report, I get an "Invalid Column Name" error with the detail field getting the error. Has anyone previously encountered this? If so, any ideas what might be causing it or how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to your question, for example the field names and any expressions you are using?

Comment: I can't add too much more detail because the database is related to my work. When I say field detail, I mean that there is a general grouping...ex. myDogs, and then the detail would be fido, igor, and fluffy. 'Detail' is not actually the name. 

In this case, the name of the field is ESun1. I don't believe that violates any Access or SQL naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name a field *detail* because that is a reserved word (used for a Form or Report property) in Access.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D)

Name the field something else.  If changing the name is not an option, try enclosing the field name in square brackets to let Access know *detail* is a field rather than the report property.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I was attempting to perform aggregate operations on report fields, rather than on fields directly from the query. I solved the problem by performing some CASE WHEN THEN ELSE statements on fields from my query to form new query results. Then, Access accepted performing aggregate ops on the direct query results.

I've accepted HansUp's answer because it was also a valid response.